# Cloud Firestore: Query two collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections in firestore: `users` and `reports`.

- Users

  - uid ( this uid is from firebase auth, required field )
  - email ( this is not required field, as i am using social media auth )
  - firstname
  - last name
- Reports

  - uid  (this uid is from firebase auth, required field, added when user add this report)
  - isCompleted ( bollean )
  - other fields

I want to get all reports, firstname and lastname of users who isCompleted is false.

#### Query

```
firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("reports")
    .where("isCompleted", "==", false)
    .get()
    .then()
    .catch()
```

#### Problem

Using this query i can get all reports whoes isCompleted is false but how can i get firstname and lastname of user who has created this report using `uid`

Comment: @MauriceNino This loads all users, not just the ones who authored the last 3 posts. While this may work fine during development, as you add more users you will be loading more and more unnecessary data.   This issue remains the same from accepted answer.

Comment: Generally speaking, firestore is optimized for reads not for writes, so the easiest and recommended way to solve this, is to just save the user data to the report. I don't know if there is any kind of useful join query with firestore. I don't really think so, as it is also not an option to load partial documents.